# How does perl handle a pattern with different quotations?

Tags: perl, sh, quotations

As https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html indicates,

> -F option specifies the pattern to split on for -a. The pattern may be surrounded by // , "" , or '' , otherwise it will be put in single quotes. You can't use literal whitespace or NUL characters in the pattern.

I tried below commands on a text, but the result is totally the same.

So what's the difference of these pattern quotation in below example?

```
$ perl -aF"\|" -lne 'print $F[0]' input
Time
2018-01-11 00:00:00
2018-01-11 00:15:00

$ perl -aF'\|' -lne 'print $F[0]' input
Time
2018-01-11 00:00:00
2018-01-11 00:15:00

$ perl -aF/\|/ -lne 'print $F[0]' input
T
2
2

$ perl -aF"|" -lne 'print $F[0]' input
T
2
2

$ perl -aF'|' -lne 'print $F[0]' input
T
2
2


$ perl -aF/|/ -lne 'print $F[0]' input
bash: /: Is a directory
```

Comment: `design-patterns` end matching patterns are two very different concepts. Tag removed.

Comment: `|` is special in the shell. You can't use it unquoted.

Comment: `perl -aF\\\| ...` also works.

Comment: `-F/\|/` causes your shell to pass `-F/|/` to `perl`.

Answer (score 7):

There are three layers of interpretation you need to consider.

The first layer is the shell. The second layer is perl's syntax for string/regex literals. The third layer is perl's regex syntax.

Let's go through your examples, one by one:

---

`"\|"` and `'\|'` both pass a two-character string (`\|`) to perl (`"` and `'` are interpreted by the shell). That's layer one.

`\|` is not surrounded by quotes, so perl adds `''` around it, forming the string `'\|'` (as in `split '\|', $_`). Perl's single-quoted strings don't treat backslash specially (unless it's followed by `\` or `'`), so perl thinks it's still a two-character string, `\|`. That's layer two.

`split` interprets its first argument as a regex. `\` has a special meaning in a regex: It escapes the following character. Thus the regex `\|` matches a single `|` (pipe character), and that's why this code splits its input on `|`. That's layer three.

---

`/\|/` passes the three-character string `/|/` to perl (`\` is interpreted by the shell). That's layer one.

`/|/` looks like something (`|`) surrounded by `//`, so perl adds nothing (`split /|/, $_`). This is parsed as a regex literal and nothing special happens here: There's a single `|`. That's layer two.

`|` has a special meaning in a regex (unless escaped by `\`): `A|B` means "match either A or B". In this case both A and B are empty, matching the empty string. Splitting on a pattern that matches the empty string results in a list of all the characters in the input string (effectively, the input string is split everywhere (at every character boundary)). That's layer three.

---

`"|"` and `'|'` both pass a one-character string (`|`) to perl (`"` and `'` are interpreted by the shell).

`|` is not surrounded by quotes, so perl adds `''` around it, forming the string `'|'` (as in `split '|', $_`). This is a simple one-character string (still just `|`). That's layer two.

`split` interprets its first argument as a regex, and as in the previous case, `|` has a special meaning ("or"), resulting in a list of single-character elements. That's layer three.

---

`|` (outside of quotes and not escaped by `\`) is a special character in the shell: It creates a pipeline.

```
perl -aF/|/ -lne 'print $F[0]' input
```

is the same as

```
perl -aF/ | / -lne 'print $F[0]' input
```

and means: Run `perl -aF/` and pipe its output into the command `/ -lne 'print $F[0]' input`. This causes an error because `/` is not a valid program, it's a directory.